# laplace equation in spherical coordinates find the solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGTie.png)how did they find this solution and determine the values of $a_{mn}$ and[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXqWk.png) $b_{mn}$

Comment: separation of variables in spherical coordinates, using the method of frobenius to solve the associated ode's, forming an infinite series from the principle of superpostion, and exploiting orthogonality of the eigenfunctions by taking inner products to solve for the coefficients in the series solution. Actually writing out all the details of this would take quite a bit of time.

Comment: @garserdt216 could you please write the details I have been struggling with it for a long time

Comment: how far did you make it